# How to access local objects in Mockito -junit test case

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a sample class:

```
public MySampleClass {

public boolean myMethod(Request request)
{
  PartOrderResponse partOrderResponse=fetchDataAndConstructResponse(request);
  boolean status=notifyResponseToUser(partOrderResponse);
  return status;
}
}
```

Now i have to write a junit to test myMethod() and My assertion should based on the variables present as part of **partOrderResponse** object.

Is there any way  I can access this **partOrderResponse** in my junit test case **so that I can put assertion on various properties of partOrderResponse.**

I am using Mockito/Power Mock.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the code you want to test in this test case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable partOrderResponse as it is a local variable in the method myMethod. However, you can (and should) "interfere" with the return value of the fetchDataAndConstructResponse method by **mocking** it with Mockito.

the way you do this is by declaring a "Mockito.when()" in your unit test such as:

you first need a Mocking stub of your Test class:

```
@Mock
Test testClassInstance;

PartOrderResponse fakeResponse = new PartOrderResponse(...);
    Mockito.when(testClassInstance.fetchDataAndConstructResponse(any())).thenReturn(fakeResponse);
    
// now call the actual method you want to test //
boolean result = testClassInstance.myMethod(...);
    
// assertions about your test //
assert(result == expectedResult)
```

the method "myMethod" will start and call fetchDataAndConstructResponse as part of its' normal operation. Mockito will catch that invocation and replace the method with a mock/stub and return the value which we specified in the "then" part.

please make sure you understand the basics of unit testing with mocks and read a guide about Mockito [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations)

Comment: You don't want to mock the class you are trying to test.